# Interface Builder Will Not Open

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

While working in Interface Builder within Xcode (4.3.2), the application froze and I had to reopen it again.

Now I am getting this error when trying to open the nib file. What gives?

[image: IB error]

I have already starting a project from scratch when this happened yesterday as I thought maybe some project files got corrupted, but now it's happened again on another project.

Any solutions?
Thanks

Comment: By the way, the console log (presuming it is the same console that is activated with NSLog (@"")), shows nothing, even though the error states to check the log for information.

Comment: I think you need to check the system console (/Applications/Utilities/Console.app)

Comment: Ic.. I'll check it out and get back to you! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console states that :

Apparently it is an Xcode problem, so I guess that is no answer at the moment to the problem :/

I think the only solution at the moment is to downgrade (Tried with Xcode 4.3.1 but still the same problem).

Can't really see any other option.